# can't get morphable property on laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism

I have a Comment and Post models as below:

Comment model relation:

```php
    public function commentable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

Post model relation:

```php
    public function comments(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable')->notReply();
    }
```

i'm try to get a post by its comment:

```php
$comments = Comment::blog()->with('commentable')->latest()->paginate(50);
```

So far there is no problem, but when i want to echo `commentable->title` on blade in `@foreach` loop,
it returns `Attempt to read property "title" on null`.
but when i use `dd($comment->commentable->title)`, it returns post title,

```php
   @foreach($comments as $key=> $comment)
       {{ dd($comment->commentable->title) }} // returns post title
       {{ $comment->commentable->title }} // returns Attempt to read property "title" on null
   @endforeach
```

I tried use method in Comment model:

```php
    public function postTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->commentable->title;
    }
```

but again it return problem on echo and returns title on `dd()`

**SOLVED:**
There was a softDeleted comment on post. When I tried to echo comment, it returned error.
if you are facing this problem, don't forget to check your db data :))

Comment: Should you not just use `->with('comments')` ?

Comment: @geertjanknapen my relation in `commentable`, if i use `with('comment')` it returns `Call to undefined relation ...`. (I tried it)

Comment: Is this `$this->morphTo();` intentionally left blank? There is no relation and hence you're facing an error Call to undefined relation.

Comment: @HassaanAli Then how it returns expected value on controller or `dd()` function??

Answer (score 1):

Once you using `dd()` it work as `dump()` and `die()`, the problem is when you trying to `dd()` checking value in a loop, it'll only dump the first value and break the loop, because of `die()`.

In your case, there probably a `$comment` doesn't have a related `commetable`, so when you loop to the `$comment`, it will get a null from `$comment->commetable`, and you will get the `Exception` when you trying to access a property `title` from null.

For a simple verification, you can try：

```php
 @foreach($comments as $key=> $comment)
       {{ !is_null($comment->commentable) ? $comment->commentable->title : 'I do not have any commentable.' }} // returns Attempt to read property "title" on null
 @endforeach
```